# Workflow not working after migration from 2013 to 2016

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have migrated SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 using content DB approach and setup workflow manager on separate server however workflow is not working after migration. it works if I edit and publish the workflow from SharePoint Designer and new workflow is also working, only existing workflows are not working.

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same situation...

Comment: Yes, I had reconfigured the workflow server and workflow client and it was working fine.

Comment: could you please explain how did you managed to fix this?

Comment: I have republished all the workflow manually from designer after the migration.